# Gaming Mouse Recommendations

Tags: 13.04, mouse, games, gamepad

**I'm looking to upgrade to a gaming mouse.**
Searching Amazon for a Linux gaming mouse isn't getting very many results. So I'm asking here for recommendations. I'm using Ubuntu 13.04 64bit Gnome Fallback Session for now.

My preferences are for:
* Wireless.
* PS2 or USB receiver.
* At least 6 assignable buttons.
* Assignable macros would be a bonus.
* Works out of the box with Linux, or at least with a simple setup.
* Accurate and dependable.
* Comfortable, as in a low profile design.

Feel free to share your own experiences or recommendations for gaming mice, joypads, or gamepads that work with Linux.

Comment: Downvotes? Really?

Comment: Sick of the trolls that have nothing better than to downvote questions. I thought this was the go-to for help, guess not. See if I ever help out with suggestions again. I'll figure it out myself.

Comment: Maybe you should read the [help], specifically [what not to ask](http://askubuntu.com/help/dont-ask) before complaining.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edit: I just read about [piper](https://github.com/libratbag/piper) on [Phoronix](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=GSoC-2017-Projects) and noticed that I missed this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/793479/40581).

**Almost all mice work with Linux, but not the software they come with.** You can configure all buttons in some configuration files, but for advanced features there probably needs to be written a Linux equivalent of the Windows software.

This is where manufacturers fail. I don't know of a manufacturer developing free and open Linux drivers and software for their mice. Of course from their point of view it's so unbelievable that all of them should combine their efforts into writing one good solution that works for Linux with every advanced gaming mouse they produce. Stoneage thinking. We've been there with WiFi, too.

**Some articles I found that may help you:**

- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/All_Mouse_Buttons_Working
- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Razer

**You should probably just choose the mouse that matches your criteria and look for solutions on how make special features work with Linux.**

Hint: A scroll wheel is no special feature, it's just 2 buttons (or 4 for a tilting scroll wheel). So it doesn't matter how many scroll wheels and buttons the mouse has, but how you assign the buttons.

Comment: I have already tried to set a mouse that had 2 extra buttons to send keystrokes (It showed up using xev in a terminal) but every method I found here and on google failed. I didn't want to spend $80 on a mouse that won't work, so I asked here for mice that can be configured in Linux. I know the windows software that comes with the mouse isn't going to work, but being able to easily configure the buttons is desirable.

Comment: The first article is great! I'll be using Easystroke to set the buttons. Now all I need to know is the actual hardware compatibility.

Comment: I believe roccat gaming mice keyboards are supported in linux. IE if your kernel doesnt support your hardware you can use the latest drivers and their software  https://launchpad.net/~berfenger/+archive/roccat   and products http://www.roccat.org/Products/ additional installation instructions http://roccat.sourceforge.net/general.html

Comment: I remember reading an announcement from Roccat but couldn't find anything back then. Would make a good answer on it's own, I think.

Answer (score 4):

**Logitech G700s Rechargeable Gaming Mouse**
I'm adding my own answer for the gaming mouse I choose.
The G700s works out of the box using Easystroke to assign button events, **but**...
Easystroke won't assign the button mapping to the mouse on-board memory, so you're pretty much stuck with one profile even though the mouse has 5 on-board profiles built in. Easystroke also wouldn't recognize one of the games executable, so It was pretty much a global setting or nothing.
I installed [Virtualbox and the VirtualBox Extension Pack](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads), put WinXP on it, downloaded and installed  [Logitech's software](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/support/wireless-gaming-mouse-g700?crid=411) for WinXP to it, and then I could assign the different profiles to the mouse on-board memory which does indeed stay with the mouse in Linux. You could also just use a Windows PC temporarily to set up the mouse, then put it back on a Linux PC, it will save the profiles in the mouse, not the operating system.

Answer (score 1):

**For other Logitech Gaming Peripherals**
There's a project called [Gnome15](http://www.russo79.com/gnome15) that supports Logitech Keyboards and Headsets...
"Gnome15 is a suite of tools for the Logitech G series keyboards and headsets, including the G15, G19, G13, G930, G35, G510, G11, G110 and the Z-10 speakers aiming to provide the best integration possible with the Linux Desktop."