# Gaming mice for Ubuntu

Tags: mouse, games, logitech

I recently was thinking to get myself a gaming mouse.
But the thing that is bothering me is that whether it will work out of the box for Ubuntu.I am looking to buy a Logitech one. Model 300s .Will the buttons be configurable ?  Compatible and support. Please Assist.

Comment: This is a deep grey shade of "is this question in the right place," but I understand that as an Ubuntu user you have a question pertaining specifically to (although not ONLY to) Ubuntu. I won't down vote, but do consider posting it in a hardware forum, as that is maybe the best place. That being said, I have a standard Logitech mouse (M100) which was cheap, but requires no drivers. It has three buttons and all either work or are configurable. I would say try it, and use `xev` or `showkey` for the other 6 buttons on the 300S.

Comment: ...that is, if you need to map those keys for any reason. Anyway good luck with it! Keep your receipt! Ubuntu has pretty great hardware support though. Cheers!

Comment: I disagree with P Smith.
We have people by the hundreds if not thousands switching to Ubuntu everyday.  Instead of them going to x number of hardware forums for all the myriad of devices it makes more logical sense for all of them to go to a one stop shop first like Askubuntu to see if anyone here has already sorted the problem.  A "canonical" area.  We need to make Ubuntu friendly for adoption and not elitist.
As for your question, I use Logitech mice and have never had a problem with them with Ubuntu.  Buttons have been configurable.

Comment: @DanglingPointer Whether hardware recommendations are considered on-topic or not has been debated since the dawn of time. Consider reading (and asking, if necessary) about it in Ask Ubuntu Meta.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/152297/how-to-configure-extra-buttons-in-logitech-mouse http://www.webupd8.org/2016/06/configure-razer-mice-in-linux-with.html https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/razer

Comment: and an important one: https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Libratbag-Announced

Comment: roccat are decent gaming mice and keyboards with linux support http://askubuntu.com/questions/570947/how-do-i-get-my-roccat-lua-mouse-fully-working-on-ubuntu-14-04-64-bit

Answer (score 6):

Searching got me to this article by [Phoronix](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Libratbag-Announced) from 2015:

> `Libratbag` currently has partial support for the Logitech HID++ 1.0 (G500, G5) and HID++ 2.0 protocols (G303), the Etekcity Scroll Alpha, Roccat Kone XTD, the G5, G9, and M705.

So that led me to this [libratbag blog](http://who-t.blogspot.nl/2015/09/libratbag-library-for-configurable-mice_16.html) and the [libratbag project page](https://github.com/libratbag/libratbag) and also to this page that [lists mice](http://libratbag.github.io/device-notes/).  Logitech has a long list on there, 2 Etekcity mice, 1 Roccat mouse and it notes that Razors are protected by a EULA.

So pick one from these Logitech devices and you should be able to get the most out of your mouse:

```
Year    Model   Driver  ID
2007    G9      1.0     c048
2008    G9x     1.0     c066
2009    G500    1.0     c068
2010    G700    1.0     c06b + c531
2011    G300    ?       c246
2011    G400         
2012    G9X     1.0     c249
2012    G600    ?    
2013    G100s        
2013    G400s   ?       c24c
2013    G500s   1.0     c24e
2013    G602         
2013    G700s   1.0      
2014    G302         
2014    G402         
2014    G502    2.0     c07d
2015    G300s   ?       c246
2015    G303    2.0     c080
```

or

```
G5
G5 2007
M325
M570
M705
MX Master
T650
```

Comment: I just read on Phoronix about https://github.com/libratbag/piper a GTK frontend for libratbag.

Answer (score 0):

I have Cooler Master Sentinel Advance 2 mice. For mice full configuration I use their official tool using Windows in Virtualbox and gave access to my USB ports. I use this even for scanner at work cause in Linux  it gave me a headache (after so many tries and configurations scanner don't want to work in Ubuntu) . So that's my advice.